# Excel para CSV filtrando colunas em python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, csv

A partir de um arquivo em excel, devo selecionar algumas colunas, mas no caso de duas colunas, além de selecionar , devo filtrá-las (default=1 , estado_civil = solteiro) e depois salvar em csv.
Cheguei ao resultado abaixo, mas sem os filtros necessários

```py
import csv
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('credito.xlsx')
df.columns.to_list()
df = df[['id', 'sexo', 'idade', 'estado_civil','default']]

print(df)
df.dtypes
```

Answer (score -2):

Olá. Para aplicar os filtros necessários você deve fazer assim:

```
import pandas as pd

# Aqui você lê o arquivo e seleciona as colunas
df = pd.read_excel('credito.xlsx', usecols=['id', 'sexo', 'idade', 'estado_civil', 'default'])

# Aqui aplicamos os filtros
df = df[(df['default'] == 1) & (df['estado_civil'] == 'solteiro')]

# Aqui guarda em CSV
df.to_csv('resultado.csv', index=False)
```

E deveria dar uma checkada nas regras do stack. De "Como Fazer uma Pergunta", para não ter problemas no futuro.

Comment: Obrigado. Realmente preciso dar uma checada na regras...kkk

Answer (score -3):

Oi, para filtrar você pode fazer assim :

```
import pandas as pd

Table1 = {'Tamanho': ['P', 'P', 'M', 'G', 'G'], 'Tipo': ['Camisa', 'Calça', 'Jaqueta', 'Meia', 'Camisa'], 'Cor': ['Azul', 'Verde', 'Azul', 'Preto', 'Rosa']}

df= pd.DataFrame(Table1, columns=['Tamanho', 'Tipo', 'Cor'])

df_filter1 = df[df.Tipo.isin(['Camisa','Calça'])]

print(df_filter1)

df_filter2 = df[df.Cor.isin(['Azul'])][df[df.Cor.isin(['Azul'])].Tipo.isin(['Camisa'])]
     
print(df_filter2)
```

A linha `df_filter2` é o mesmo que fazer :

```
df_filter2 = df[df.Cor.isin(['Azul'])
df_filter2 = df_filter2[df_filter2.Tipo.isin(['Camisa'])]
```

Para enviar para um CSV:

```
df.to_csv('File.csv', index=False)
```

Onde é `df` é o dataframe que quer no CSV, 'File.csv' é o nome do arquivo, `index= False` é para não aparecer os índices.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!